# howto inject context execution at test time of a single spring batch step?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, spring-batch, inject

I would like to inject, in a single step test (so "at test time"), some context values that are provided at runtime of my sprint batch steps flow.

I have already browsed [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/testing.html).
But it's not very clear...

Below my simple test case, enriched by what i red [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/testing.html).
There must be an error because i see no effect of my injection even if i enter fine into the getStepExecution() :

```html
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:launch-context.xml" })
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, StepScopeTestExecutionListener.class })   // Inject feature enablers ?
public class ImportJobOrganisationViaRouting extends DwhITest {
 
 protected static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ImportJobOrganisationViaRouting.class);

 @Autowired
 protected  JobLauncher jobLauncher;

 @Autowired
 @Qualifier("myjob")
 protected  Job job;

 protected JobParameters jobParameters;
 
 private static JobExecution jobExecution;

 // Inject values in here ?...
 public StepExecution getStepExection() {
  System.out.println("!!!!!! TEST inject EXECUTION STEP !!!!!!!");
  StepExecution execution = MetaDataInstanceFactory.createStepExecution();
  execution.getExecutionContext().putLong("dateKey", 200);
  return execution;
 }

 
 @Test
 public void launch() throws JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, JobParametersInvalidException {
  
  jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("currTime", System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();
  jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
  assertEquals(BatchStatus.COMPLETED, jobExecution.getStatus());

 }
```

How to deal with this need ?

*A lttle help would be deeply appreciated.*

*Thx in advance, ;-)*

Comment: In your question you state that you want to execute a `Step`, yet in your test, you're executing a job.  Which do you want to do?

Comment: True, Michael !
Here it's a job i want to execute.
But it could be also a single step. Say it's a single step i want to test with injected values in its context...

Comment: Few months later... for those interested by this thread: response is here : http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/testing.html

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the JobLauncherTestUtils, you have to :

```
StepExecution execution= MetaDataInstanceFactory.createStepExecution(); 

... //fill your context
jobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep("myStep", execution.getExecutionContext())
```